# The PDOException 'could not find driver' and display_errors quandary

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I normally develop with a "warnings as errors" approach. However, recently I reinstalled my development tools, and found that I didn't have all the warnings and errors turned on like I normally do.

So, in my php.ini file, I turned the following settings back on:

```
Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Now I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\wamp\www\project\database_class_example.php
```

I'm using PDO and connecting to a PostgreSQL database. I've had this error before, but have since got it working. Here's my conundrum:

**If I turn the warnings and errors off, it works and connects to the database successfully. If I turn warnings and errors on, it doesn't.**

How is this possible, if it can't find the driver, surely it should never work!

It complains about this line of code:

```
parent::__construct($this->data_source_name, $this->username, $this->password);
```

This is from my database class, and it extends PDO.

Where **$data_source_name** is a string, which is built up beforehand, containg the **database engine name**, **host** and **database name**.

**$username** and **$password** obviously containing the username and password.

Please bare in mind, this works. If I turn off display_errors, this code works.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help me. I can't even find in my configs what that answer is recommending.

Comment: No offense, but you are not being helpful. They may have the same error, but different specifics.

Comment: You could have a working connect after the non-working connect which emits the warning, the 2nd shadowing the 1st. Hard to say without more code to look at. Ideally produce a reproducible example with full code.

Comment: I never knew that, that seems strange. Hmmm, let me improve my question by making a reproducible example, and full code.

Comment: If this is to be marked as duplicate, please point me to an previously answered question, that answers this question. The suggested one above, doesn't. I don't see how this is a duplicate. There is no, "PHPIniDir" in my Apache httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

Although the question sounds quite odd, the only cause I can guess of is you have *unused* PDO connection in the database_class_example.php. I'd be happy to provide the line number where to look for, but for some reason you omitted it from the cited error message.

The file name also suggests so.

Comment: I've edited the file name. I'll post the line of code it complains about.